# Database connect-one single quote between double quote php

Tags: php, mysql, quote

```
$data = "INSERT into detail(id,event) VALUES (1,"quest '15")";
```

Im having trouble with the single quote  `'15`.i tried to use `\'15` but doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Your string is delimited by double quotes. Use single quotes for the value, and escape the one in the middle.

Comment: Just use prepared statements and be done with it.

Comment: Give your code like this......


$data = "INSERT into detail(id,event) VALUES (1,\"quest '15\")";

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$data = "INSERT into detail(id,event) VALUES (1,\"quest '15'\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$data = "INSERT into detail(id,event) VALUES (1,'quest \'15')";

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the single quote; the problem is the use of double quotes within a string literal that is enclosed in double quotes. Your double quoted string literal is actually being *ended* right before `quest`.

One alternative is to use single quotes for string literals within SQL text. Within a string literal, you'll need to "escape" the single quote, and one way to do that is by preceding a single quote by another single quote.

For example:

```
$data = "INSERT into detail(id,event) VALUES (1,'quest ''15')";
                                                ^      ^^  ^
```

If you do that, the value for the `event` column will be seen as **`quest '15`**

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using prepared statements, but in lieu of that, you can use mysqli_real_escape_string.

```
$data "INSERT INTO detail (id, event) VALUES (1, '".mysqli_real_escape_string("quest '15")."')";
```